# How to define variants in build system for Latex in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text, build-system

After the new LatexTools plugin was released, I am unable to get the follwoing functionality which I had in the previous LatexTools plugin.

I tend to use the sequence latex-dvipdfm the most(Build: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>), but I also needed pdflatex (Run: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and xelatex (Xelatex in build menu).

The following bit of code in the Latex.sublime-build  file used to accomplish that.

```
"cmd": ["latexmk",
        "-e","\\$dvipdf = 'dvipdfmx %O -o %D %S'", "-e", "\\$latex = 'latex %O -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S'",
        "-f", "-pdfdvi"],


        "variants":
        [

            { "cmd": ["latexmk",
            "-e", "\\$pdflatex = 'pdflatex %O -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S'",
            "-f", "-pdf"],
            "name": "Run"
            },


            { "cmd": ["latexmk",
            "-e", "\\$pdflatex = 'xelatex %O -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S'",
            "-f", "-pdf"],
            "name": "xelatex"
            },

        ]
```

I am unable tweak the Latextools.sublime-settings file and get this to work under the new LatexTools plugin. Could anyone suggest a way to tweak the build system to achieve this ?
Thanks.

**EDIT**:
I had posed the question to the creator of the LatexTools plugin and he was kind enough to reply. I am posting his reply as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Marciano Siniscalchi, the developer of the plugin, said:

> "Unfortunately what you need to do is not feasible at the moment. The
>   new build code bypasses the variants mechanism. If there is enough
>   demand, I could implement it though."